# AngularJS, Karma - Clearing ng-dirty with setPristine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

In one of my unit tests I'm trying to test if ng-dirty gets removed when I setPristine on an input element.  After calling setPristine on the element I can see ng-dirty is not being removed.

I have a feeling I am calling the setPristine method incorrectly.

The logic I am trying to test for is as follows

1. Add text to your input then
2. Test for ng-dirty set the setPristine
3. then check for ng-dirty again

n

```
/** 
    Add text to your input,
    then test for ng-dirty set the setPristine,
    then check for ng-dirty again. 
*/
it('should set pristine', function() {
    element = angular.element('<input ng-model="temp"></input>');
    element = compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    element.val("Some Input");
    element.triggerHandler("change");
    expect(element.hasClass('ng-dirty')).toBe(true);    
    element.triggerHandler('setPristine');
    console.log(element);
    expect(element.hasClass('ng-dirty')).toBe(false);       
});
```

Which then logs

```
<input ng-model="temp" class="ng-scope ng-valid ng-dirty">
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$setPristine` is a method exposed on Angular's [`FormController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine) and [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setPristine).

So if you have a form named `myForm`:

```
<form name="myForm"></form>
<div ng-form="myForm"></form>
```

You can call `myForm.$setPristine()` to set all controls within it to pristine.

The same concept applies to individual controls:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" ng-model="temp"></input>
</form>
```

You can call `myForm.myInput.$setPristine()` to set that specific control to pristine.

You shouldn't be testing for the `ng-dirty` classes being added/removed, that's getting into the implementation details of `$setPristine` itself. If the Angular devs changed `ng-dirty` to `ng-filthy` tomorrow, your tests would break.

Instead, you can trust that the Angular developers have their own tests covering the addition and removal of CSS classes and you should be concerned with testing that your code calls `$setPristine` correctly, i.e.:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    element = angular.element(
        '<form name="myForm">' +
        '   <input name="myInput" ng-model="temp"></input>' + 
        '</form>'
    );
    element = compile(element)(scope);

    myForm = scope.myForm;
    spyOn(myForm, '$setPristine');
});

it('should set pristine', function () {
    // call your code

    // then assert
    expect(myForm.$setPristine).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the example and explanation, thank you this helped a great deal.